# The item "obj\Debug\DateSelector.resources" was specified more than once in the "Resources" parameter.

Tags: c#

I convert my huge website into web application. My application already have DateSelector.cs code file name, which is being used extensively in Project. Now Please tell me a way around that how can i stop on compilation the obj folder to not create DateSelector.resources file.

Comment: Try deleting the obj folder and rebuiding.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a solution-wide search for "DateSelector.Resources" ?  See if it turns up in one of the 'meta' files, it might just be listed twice.